# How to see what viewcontroller was presented modally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to TDD everything in one of my apps, is there a way to see if a ViewController was popped up Modal-wise?

As in, if in a logic branch I call:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myModalControl];
```

is there a way to test this on the viewcontroller that's presenting?

I tried:

```
[mainVC_SUT presentedViewController]
```

and

```
[mainVcSUT modalViewController]
```

but both comes back as nil.  mainVC_SUT is the viewcontroller that does the presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Check like like:

```
 if ([self.parentViewController.modalViewController isEqual:self])
    NSLog(@"I'm modal view controller!");
else 
    NSLog(@"I'm a push view controller!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)isModal {

    BOOL isModal = ((self.parentViewController && self.parentViewController.modalViewController == self) || 
                    //or if I have a navigation controller, check if its parent modal view controller is self navigation controller
                    ( self.navigationController && self.navigationController.parentViewController && self.navigationController.parentViewController.modalViewController == self.navigationController) || 
                    //or if the parent of my UITabBarController is also a UITabBarController class, then there is no way to do that, except by using a modal presentation
                    [[[self tabBarController] parentViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]);

    //iOS 5+
    if (!isModal && [self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {

        isModal = ((self.presentingViewController && self.presentingViewController.modalViewController == self) || 
                   //or if I have a navigation controller, check if its parent modal view controller is self navigation controller
                   (self.navigationController && self.navigationController.presentingViewController && self.navigationController.presentingViewController.modalViewController == self.navigationController) || 
                   //or if the parent of my UITabBarController is also a UITabBarController class, then there is no way to do that, except by using a modal presentation
                   [[[self tabBarController] presentingViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]);

    }

    return isModal;        

}
```

*Credit:* http://www.allenwei.cn/ios-determine-current-view-is-a-modal/